# How to perform operations with vertices from any edge on a Graph object

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to get the vertices from an large list of edges on a `Graph` object in *Mathematica* 10. I need to operate them, adding, substracting dividing.

As an example of what I want, consider the following list of edges:

```
{0 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12, 7 -> 14}
```

I need a count of those edges whose difference between end vertices are 6. Only `{4 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12}` meet that requirement. So I would like to get a count of 3 from the first list.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For your example the following works.

```
edges = {0 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12, 7 -> 14};
Count[edges, Rule[u_, v_] /; v - u == 6]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Now let's verify that I am actually counting the right edges.

```
Cases[edges, Rule[u_, v_] /; v - u == 6]
```

> ```
> {4 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 12}
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I had a mistake in my main question. The arrow it is meant to be a $\[DirectedEdge]$ operator of mathematica for directed edges no the operator -> so i need to modify your answer to get what i want.

Comment: @MonseYahmed. Try substituting `DirectedEdge[u_, v_]` for `Rule[u_, v_]`

Comment: Yay! It worked! Thanks a lot